# Understanding Ruby method parameters syntax

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument

I've been following an RSpec tutorial on Pluralsight for creating a basic card game.  When the class is defined as such:

```
class Card
  def initialize(suit:, rank:)
    @suit = suit
    @rank =
      case rank
      when :jack then 11
      when :queen then 12
      when :king then 13
      else rank
      end
  end
end
```

the RSpec test code is for example:

```
RSpec.describe 'a playing card' do
  it 'has a suit' do
    raise unless Card.new(suit: :spades, rank: 4).suit == :spades
  end
end
```

I haven't encountered method parameter syntax like this `(suit: :spades, rank: 4)`. Can someone explain what this means, or point me in the right direction on where to look this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called *keyword arguments*. Unlike *positional arguments*, you can pass them in any order, but you have to provide their names. This can greatly improve readability, especially for methods with higher arity. [More on the subject](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)

Comment: Thanks. I realised I have come across this before, in setting default arguments if none are specified (must have been codecademy course).

Comment: @ggwc Defaults (`def m(a = 6)`) are slightly different, an argument with a default doesn't have to specified at all (i.e. both `m()` and `m(11)` work), named arguments unpack an argument hash into local variables (more or less).